# How to find all previous owners of a domain

Tags: domain, whois

Everyone knows that it is possible to find the owner of a domain using whois, but a person asked me if it was possible to know all the previous owners of a domain. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are a variety of Whois History lookups such as [Domain Tools](http://www.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/), most of which are paid services.

These services are merely archives of whois records, but should serve your purpose.